# Why doesn't Tor use garlic routing?

Tags: onion-routing, i2p, tor-network, garlic-routing

Garlic routing is a variant of onion routing which the Invisible Internet Project (I2P) uses. Why doesn't Tor use garlic routing instead of onion routing?